# C# Reusing an Adapter to populate other controls

Tags: c#, database, datatable

I'm using the following code to populate a DataGridView (sqliteAdapter derives from DbDataAdapter):

```
sqliteAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = SQLCommand;
sqliteConn.Open();
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    sqLiteAdapter.Fill(dt);
    dataGridRes.DataSource = dt;
}
```

The Actual SQLCommand is:

```
SELECT Email NOTNULL AS Sel, Regiao, Distrito, Grupo, MG, ID, Nome, Morada, Email
FROM assessores
```

Now, I would like to reuse this DataTable to populate other controls in the form. Namely 4 CheckedListBox controls. I was hoping to avoid any further connections to the database by "filtering" the current DataTable to something like (Invalid code. Illustrative only)

```
SELECT Distinct Regiao FROM DataTable
SELECT Distinct Distrito FROM DataTable
SELECT Distinct Grupo FROM DataTable
SELECT Distinct MG FROM DataTable
```

My forays into adapter and DataTable properties and methods have been fruitless.

Comment: It's perfectly valid under SQLite and it works, make no mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls can be bound to any collection, not just a DataTable.
You can therefore use LINQ, like this:

```
myControl.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("Regiao")).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Perfect. Still need to learn about LINQ. But this solves my immediate problems. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a DataTable but it returns an array of DataRow objects rather than a filtered DataTable, which can't be directly bound to a DataGrid or other data bound control. Instead use a DataView:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = "Filter Expresion";

dg.DataSource = dv;
```

See [Sorting and Filtering Data Using a DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13wb36xf(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: This was part ofg my initial attempts, but I couldn't find a way to retrieve distinct data from a column. Hence I abandoned it.